# How to make a javascript comparison more concise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following two javascript objects:

Object A:

```
{
  specialPropertyA: string,
  partTime: boolean,
  role: { key: string, label: string }
}
```

Object B:

```
{
  specialPropertyB: string,
  partTime: boolean,
  role: { key: number, label: string }
}
```

Now, consider an `arrayA: ObjectA[]` and an `arrayB: ObjectB[]`.

I am looking for a concise way to determine:

If any of the ObjectA's have `partTime === true` AND `role.key === 1`, are there any ObjectBs, which fulfill the same requirements? I want to check the same for `role.key === 2`.

I know I could do sth like:

```
if(
    arrayA.filter(objectA => objectA.partTime === true && objectA.role.key === 1) 
    && arrayB.filter(objectB => objectB.partTime === true && objectB.role.key === 1) 
    || arrayA.filter(objectA => objectA.partTime === true && objectA.role.key === 2)
    && arrayB.filter(objectB => objectB.partTime === true && objectB.role.key === 2)
  )
```

But I don't like this solution at all, especially since I am repeating the same code for key 2. Any suggestions as on how to make this more concise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to make a higher-order function that you can pass the key number you want to find.

Also, because `partTime` is a boolean, `obj.partTime === true` simplifies to `obj.partTime`.

```
const makeCb = keyNum => obj => obj.partTime && obj.role.key === keyNum;

if (
  (arrayA.some(makeCb(1)) && arrayB.some(makeCb(1))) ||
  (arrayA.some(makeCb(2)) && arrayB.some(makeCb(2)))
) {
```

You'll want `.some` (or `.find`, if you want to put the result into a variable). `.filter` won't work in an `if` because even if there are no results, empty arrays are truthy.

Comment: this looks very interesting! I am not familiar with this nested notation though. The way I understand it is: `makeCb()` takes in a parameter `keyNum` and returns a function, which takes in the parameter `obj` and returns `obj.partTime && obj.role.key === keyNum`. Is that correct?

Comment: It's [just currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) - a higher-order function, a function that returns a function, yes

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays have many possible key values, which could match, then maybe first collect the found key values in the first array before scanning the second:

```
const keysA = new Set(arrayA.map(({partTime, key}) => partTime && key));
if (arrayB.some(({partTime, key}) => partTime && keysA.has(key))) {
  /* ... */
}
```

This assumes that `false` is not a possible value of `key`.